Save IMAP email without active account
I used the default Samsung Email app that came with my Samsung Galaxy Note 10. I provided the IMAP details to get emails on my phone. I got rid of the paid account before I got the new phone. I don't have that account anymore.
I can fully open and read all incoming and outgoing. It is doing this while offline, with no wifi or mobile data. Tech support says to screenshot them, but I don't have time since it has too many emails.
How can I transfer the old emails from the old phone to a new phone or to a PC? Any suggestions?

Hi. This question looks on-topic here, so I cleaned up some meta-commentary. That said, this question is tagged with [tag:samsung-email]. Is your "old Android phone" a Samsung phone? Could you mention the exact device model and Android version, just in case? Also, I assume the emails are still shown on the old phone?

@Andrew T. Thanks for responding. Samsung Galaxy Note 10 US version. Not sure of the Android version. Probably the latest Samsung updated to before stopping Note 10 updates. It is the Samsung default email app that looks like envelopen with red background. Yes i can fully open and read all incoming and outgoing. It is doing this while offline no wifi or mobile data

IMAP only saves emails on the IMAP server. Locally mails are just temporary cached data which can be erased at any time. Usually IMAP clients do provide methods for migration such data as the actually data store is the IMAP server. You should have saved the mails from your IMAP server before terminating the IMAP contract, or copied them to a different (free) IMAP server like Google Mail.

@Robert thanks for responding. When I had switched phones in the past it did it automatically. I assumed it was Smartswitch not the IMAP doing it. So I did not bother when canceling. So are you telling me it cannot be moved to my new phone or pc?

To a PC I don't think this is possible because you don't get access to the data of Samsung E-Mail (even adb backup isn't possible). Moving to a new Samsung phone via Smartswitch - maybe. I don't have much experience between Samsung to Samsung migration via Smartswitch. To a different brand I don't think this is possible. When it comes to data migration from one mail app to another and the data belongs to an IMAP account I don't think anybody did implement a migration way as simply loading the data from IMAP is usually the easier way.

Smartswitch can't do it. Support said it needs to re-download the emails from the server. So there is no way to save the cache files to pc or another phone or USB drive? "work with the files in Cache and Database and reverse / decode them (reverse java) back to emails" did this person ever found a solution because it looks like my issuel
